# Automatic downloading stopped due to the proper MIME type mismatch

Tags: ruby, mime-types, selenium-webdriver, ruby-1.9.3

I have written one script to download files automatically from the web as below:

```
#Automatically download files to a given folder profile settings
#---------------------------------------------------------------
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['browser.download.dir'] = 'C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\userdata\Rubydownloads'
profile['browser.download.folderList'] = 2
profile['browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk'] = "application/pdf,application/x-pdf,application/acrobat,application/vnd.pdf,text/pdf,text/x-pdf,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg,image/gif,image/bmp,image/x-windows-bmp,image/tif,image/x-tif,image/tiff,image/x-tiff,application/tif,application/x-tif,application/tiff,application/x-tiff"
profile['browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting'] = false
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :profile => profile
```

But my bad, some of the `.tif,.tiff and .pdf` still missed without being download. Can it be done, say - if proper `mime type` not found in the above profile settings,then the script should add that `mime` to the browser settings,to continue downloading ?

Please help me here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working through a similar problem.

I'm not sure if you're missing mime-types in your `neverAsk.saveToDisk` list (it doesn't look like it), but I'll suggest that the following may help:

```
profile['browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force'] = 'false'
```